# Unreal engine: How to get FHitResult.FaceIndex?

Tags: raycasting, unreal-engine4

When I do

```
  PlayerController->GetHitResultUnderCursor(ECollisionChannel::ECC_WorldDynamic, false, TraceResult);
```

TraceResult.FaceIndex is always `-1`.

[Here](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/50830/does-anything-set-fhitresultfaceindex.html) @OriCohen says that I have to "use a triangle mesh for the query". Do I have to use `GetHitResultUnderCursorForObjects()` with "triangle mesh" for the object type? Then how should I do it (EObjectTypeQuery is very obscure to me)?

[Here](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/280234/edit.html) is the question on UE4 answerhub.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain a valid FaceIndex you need to make sure bReturnFaceIndex and bTraceComplex are set to true in your FCollisionQueryParams.